# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') but i've manually changed Nan values in my database to equal 0

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I've been having trouble with my regression formula. my dataset hasn't got any Nan values as I went through my database and replaced any blank cells with the value of 0. I have a feeling its because i have read into 3 different databases?
this is my current code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from scipy import stats

covid = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ISAAC\Documents\Business Analytics\Capstone project\complete covid database.csv')
covid.head() 

covidEA = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ISAAC\Documents\Business Analytics\Capstone project\europe north america.csv')
covidEA.head()

covidEU = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ISAAC\Documents\Business Analytics\Capstone project\europe.csv')
covidEU.head()

feature = ['total_vaccinations']
label = ['new_deaths']

x = covidEU[feature]
y = covidEU[label]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y)

linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(x_train, y_train),
```

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. Did you try investigating the data in the dataframes you are creating from CSVs? The error (based on the title of your post) may be due to something other than NaN's.

Comment: @AlexK I looked at my dataset and thought it could be because i had some missing values where one variable had a value and the comparing variable didn't but i used the excel 'go to' - 'special' to fill in blanks with the value of 0 , i'm not sure what else to try. thankyou for the comment

Comment: You need to check the contents of your pandas dataframes.  `read_csv()` could have added some extra rows or changed values. Look up the documentation of the `read_csv()` function and make sure you are using it the right way.